Error (index):3156 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. in my extension
manifest.json:
{
    "name": "setence break down py",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Destrinchar sentenças gramaticalmente",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "webRequest", "storage"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "breakdown.html",
        "default_title": "sentence breakdown"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}


background.js:
/*const { OpenAI } = require('openai');*/

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "acionarpy",
    title: "acionarpy",
    contexts: ["selection"]
  });
});

var selecao

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {

  selecao = info.selectionText
  if (info.menuItemId === "acionarpy") {
    chrome.windows.create({
        type: "popup",
        url: "breakdown.html",
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    });
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if (message.action === "janelaCriada") {
      console.log("menssagem")
      console.log(selecao)
      sendResponse({
        resposta: selecao
      })
  }
});

contentScript.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    if (message.action === "janelaCriada") {
        console.log( window.getSelection().toString())
        sendResponse({
          resposta: "cs"
        })
    }
  });

breakdown.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>breakdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<main class="container-fluid py-5 text-center">
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </main>-->
    <div>
        <h2>Texto selecionado: </h2>
        <p id="selectedText">-</p>
    </div>

    <form name="call" id="call" action="/call" method="post">
        <input type="text" value="">
    </form>

    <div>
        <p id="tg">+</p>
    </div>

    <script src="breakdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

breakdown.js:



var texto

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("breakdown");

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "janelaCriada"}, async function(response){
    console.log("menssagem no breakdown:")
    console.log(response.resposta)
    texto = response.resposta
    console.log("texto:", texto)
    document.getElementById("selectedText").textContent = response.resposta
    document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value = response.resposta
    document.call.submit();
  });
};

teste.py:
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, g
from flask_session import Session

import os
import google.generativeai as genai

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/call", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def api_call():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        call_prompt = request.form.get("call")
        print(call_prompt)
        return None
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

this is what the popup  console looks like:
menssagem
background.js:29 trouble
(index):3156 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):3156
why is this error happening?
I wanted to send the form value to the flask app (i'm planning to do something else with this value in there), and print it, so i could test the value update

This error is shown when the URL is invalid or doesn't exist (the error page itself in Chrome non-JS module files, which is what the error says). It's unclear how flask is related to your extension. Note that the errors shown in chrome://extensions page are from the past, so you need to clear/remove them.

@wOxxOm, hey, thanks for answering, the flsk is suposed to get a text that was selected as make and become a variable in the flask file, then return a result in the popup, the error it self is in the popup console.

The /call action in the form redirects to the same html file inside the extension and not to your flask app, which is why the error is shown as there's no such path inside your extension. You should use a full localhost URL I guess.
